# Make an object of functions from an array or strings?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a nodejs webserver (ServerA) running expressjs but I have some code I need to keep separate from another github repo so I'm building a second webserver (ServerB) (nodejs, expressjs) that can be called from ServerA.

On ServerA I'm replacing the functions that I'm moving with this code:

```
async function functionAMovedToServerB(...args) {
    const functionName = new Error().stack.split("at ")[1].trim().split(".")[1].split(" ")[0];
    logger.trace(`${functionName}()`);
    return post(functionName, args);
}
async function functionBMovedToServerB(...args) {
    const functionName = new Error().stack.split("at ")[1].trim().split(".")[1].split(" ")[0];
    logger.trace(`${functionName}()`);
    return post(functionName, args);
}
async function functionCMovedToServerB(...args) {
    const functionName = new Error().stack.split("at ")[1].trim().split(".")[1].split(" ")[0];
    logger.trace(`${functionName}()`);
    return post(functionName, args);
}

export default {
    functionAMovedToServerB, 
    functionBMovedToServerB, 
    functionCMovedToServerB
};
```

The `post()` function is just a wrapper around a `fetch()` call.

I have a lot of functions I'm moving over, is there a way to take an array of strings and create the function list above?

Or better yet, is there a better way to call another server?

Comment: These 3 functions are identical, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, except for the name which is passed to the `post()` function